# How to install and push Netsuite bundle from eclipse , instead of creating a suitebundler

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We have access to Netsuite production account but not to Sandbox account. I am creating roles,center tabs,workflows directly in Netsuite And for Scripts using the suitecloud plugin in eclipse to push the code into filecabinet.

I am aware that we can create a bundle using Suitebundler and give shared access to other account and install it there . But i dont have access to other accounts, so in this case what is the best way to test what i have created ?

I am looking for some solution like downloading the scripts,xmls(for roles,center tabs,workflows) into eclipse and then delete everything whatever i have created in netsuite to keep it fresh. And then push it from eclipse into netsuite account and test it.

Can someone please advice . Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [SDF (SuiteCloud Development Framework)](https://system.na2.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_4702622163.html) which does almost exactly that.

> SuiteCloud Development Framework (SDF) is a development framework and
>   deployment mechanism. It provides a foundation for a structured
>   development process and supports familiar development concepts and
>   patterns.
>
> You can use SDF to create SDF project components, sometimes referred
>   to as customizations, for internal use within your organization or for
>   commercial distribution. These file-based projects use XML definitions
>   of custom NetSuite objects, such as custom records, custom forms, and
>   workflows. SDF projects also support SuiteScript files. You can use
>   SDF to deploy SDF projects to your NetSuite account.
>
> SuiteCloud IDE is an Eclipse-based or WebStorm-based integrated
>   development environment (IDE) that is packaged for NetSuite platform
>   development. SuiteCloud IDE interfaces with SDF and enables you to
>   create SDF projects. For more information about SuiteCloud IDE, see
>   SuiteCloud IDE for Eclipse Overview and SuiteCloud IDE for WebStorm
>   Overview.
>
> SuiteCloud Development Framework Command Line Interface (CLI) is a
>   tool that can be used with your IDE to develop SDF projects. You can
>   also create batch and shell scripts that use CLI commands to automate
>   SDF project validation and deployment processes. For more information
>   about CLI, see Command Line Interface Guide.